# Eclipse watch expression?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I want the eclipse debugger to watch when a certain expression becomes true (its value changes) and halt when that happens. This seems to me to be very useful and basic, so I'm thinking there must be a way to do this in eclipse (as in gdb). I don't want a breakpoint with a condition since I don't know which statement will make the expression true, and I don't want a watchpoint since that only applies to variables in the program, not arbitrary expressions. Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from my searches online and the responses I got, I guess eclipse doesn't support this.

Comment: I agree. Haven't heard of this feature yet. In Eclipse you'd have to put conditional break points with the same condition in every line that could potentially change the outcome of your expression.